# Same regex for client-side and server-side validation

Tags: javascript, php, regex, email, pcre

I am trying to find out whether my client-side Javascript regex

```
/^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/
```

for email validation (I'm using it just to make sure that the email is formatted properly, not as a primary validation method) will work on the server side with PHP.

I am not sure whether I can use the same one even though both languages use Perl-based regex syntax. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You don't need a regex to validate an email address in php: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php

Comment: @MarcellFülöp What's the quickest way to test? I haven't wrote the PHP script yet.

Comment: Are you trying to say that you don't have the ability to test on that server, or you need a way of testing? Take a look at http://www.regexr.com/ to verify your results (of the regex alone). Note: Your regex is more complicated than it needs to be to verify email addresses.

Comment: @Signus I decided to use this one instead /^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]{2,})+$/ and it seems to work with both JS and PHP. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex will work nearly identically in both JavaScript and PHP. There are some minuscule differences, for example `\s` matches the "next line" control character `U+0085` in PHP, but not in JavaScript, but they are unlikely to matter in this context (it's unusual anyway to allow newlines and tabs in email addresses - why not use a simple space instead of the generic whitespace shorthand `\s`).

If you have to do these kinds of comparisons/conversions regularly, I heartily recommend you taking a look at [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com) which can convert regexes between flavors with a single click.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use the same syntax.
You should use
[preg_match(String $pattern, String $email[, array $matches])](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)
with your pattern. It puts all occurrences into the array $matches, if given.
It returns true if a match is found. For E-Mails in particular it's always a
better idea to use the functions of others, because for example "$@us" is a valid
email address